# SQLDeveloper not starting

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, java-home

When i try to start SQLDeveloper, it is giving me the following error in command prompt:

```
Error: This product requires a Java(TM) Platform 5.0 runtime.
You are using 1.4.2-b28 from C:\j2sdk1.4.2\jre
```

But my JAVA_HOME is set to java 6

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
```

Can anyone explain what exactly to do to resolve this?

Comment: What version can you see installed if you look in Programs and Features (Add remove programs)?

Answer (score 19):

Oracle SQL Developer uses a configuration file named products.conf which is situated at your roaming directory.

If you are using Windows 7 then the directory path will be:
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0

1. Delete whole sqldeveloper directory from C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\
2. Re run sqldeveloper executable, this will prompt for jdk home
3. Select jdk home. i.e C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
4. Enjoy!

Answer (score 11):

In my case i had 2 folders under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\`

1. sqldeveloper
2. SQL developer

after removing both of them and launching installation `dir\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper64.exe` it worked.

Comment: Thank you!! I lost so much time trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 2):

True acknowledgement / attribution belongs to Vishal at the following URL:
http://vishalorcl.blogspot.com/2012/12/sql-developer-from-11201-client-software.html. It describes in detail how to resolve this problem. From the page:

> I am running Oracle 11g version of SQLDeveloper.   I have same problem
>   noted above, after fresh install of Oracle. The summary is that
>   SQLDeveloper seems to require the Java 32-bit JDK.
>
> Install 32-bit jdk V7 from Oracle:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
>
> There is a sqldeveloper.conf file located in 
>   C:\app\UserName\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin
>
> In the file change pathname within the line at end of file:
>   SetJavaHome C:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdk
>
> To point to pathname of the jdk install directory; also sometimes
>   known as JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too!
you should go to:  C:\Users-your user name-\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper-version of your sql developer-
there is a file named product.conf there. Right click on it and edit it with notepad in the document change the address of java home and save it.
Done!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the other suggestions worked. Instead, I moved the installation directory from

```
c:\sqldeveloper
```

to

```
anything else
```

And things worked again. Perhaps, some Windows registry value got broken in an unfixable way...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SQLDeveloper uses the environment variable.  There should be a .conf file that contains a reference to the JDK directory.

Comment: There is a conf file named jdk.conf.But it is empty

Comment: According to this post http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/oracle-sql-developer-4-windows-and-the-jdk/ there should be a product.conf file.  In it is a SetJavaHome setting that should point to the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting the folder /home/USERNAME/.sqldeveloper
After that, I started SQLDeveloper and without typing anything, it found the right java-version and started without complaining :-)

So, if you don't want to delete the whole folder, maybe search there for the file which defines the java-version :-)

edit: just found that: 
"Type the full pathname of a J2SE installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path
will be stored in ~/.sqldeveloper/jdk"

Answer (score 0):

check the version of java that you are installing to you Pc the error show that you are using 4 so uninstall the java that you have then install a new one that is version higher than 5

Answer (score 0):

Removing the instances from the registry worked for me.