# SQL Worksheet is not displaying in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suddenly SQL worksheet is not displaying in my SQL Developer. When I click on '**Open SQL Worksheet**' or <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> nothing will appear.

I have tried many things such as: uninstalling SQL developer; cleaned the appData; changing java version; change SQL Developer version; and so on. But nothing has worked. Help?

Comment: Try deleting............
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\Version\product.conf

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work

Comment: Damn - I had the same happen to me and that appeared to work for me.
Sorry.
Either way, I did find the solution via a bit of googling so the answer is out there.  I'm up to my kneck at thye moment or else I'd have tried to find the solution again for you.
One other think that springs to mind in the ORACLE_HOME env var....
For me it was.....
Via cmd....
SET ORACLE_HOME=D:\app\AD2\product\11.2.0
So adjust as necessary if not set.

Not certain it will help though.

Answer (score 4):

Try to open Sql Developer as administrator. It's weird but works for me.

Comment: Just ran into this issue (cannot get SQLDeveloepr to display a SQL worksheet).  Running as admin resolved the issue (Thanks!) . . . Ran into the problem using an ancient version of SQLDeveloper (4.1.5.21) from the desktop of a DFARS-compliant Windows Server 2019 machine.

Answer (score 0):

While any the software - SQLDeveloper got error or something worng.

You can try to 
backup whole sqldeveloper directory from C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\
then delete it.

But remember to backup your customer infomation!

Or reference this [SQLDeveloper not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810318/sqldeveloper-not-starting)

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I clear folder C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\SqlHistory. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was path problem. I changed path of temp and TMP in environment variable to `C:\Users\____\Appdata\Local\Temp`

Then worksheet showed up again. somehow I changed this path before, that was the reason for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by :

1. Closing SQL developer
2. Deleting the file `SqlHistory.xml` that is located at `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\`. Alternatively, you can rename it to e.g `SqlHistoryOLD.xml`

Now when you open SQL developer and create a new SQL worksheet, it will work :)