# Oracle SQL Developer SQL Worksheet not opening

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have `Oracle SQL Developer v4.1.3`. Currently I am able to connect with my database. But after connecting to database when I try to open SQL Worksheet, nothing happen. I am not able to open my `SQL Worksheet`.
I try to open 'Open SQL Worksheet' or Alt+F10, but nothing will be happen.

When I try to connect to database, I successfully connect to database but I am getting below error on log pane.

[image]

I download the new version of `Oracle SQL Developer v4.1.5`. But I am facing same issue.

I already see one post ([SQL Worksheet is not displaying in SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435595/sql-worksheet-is-not-displaying-in-sql-developer)) related to this question. But it will not help me.
**I am using Oracle SQL Developer as direct run not installed.**

**I have windows 10 and jdk1.8.0_60 (64bit) installed.**

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: What happens when you test or open the connection?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am able to connect with my database. But after connecting to database when I try to open SQL Worksheet, nothing happen.

Comment: right click on connection > 'Open SQL Worksheet' - does that do anything? Do you see any messages written to the log panel? If you click on Window menu, and then 'Documents...' do you see anything listed?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Where is the log panel? Can you please help me to find that?

Comment: View > Log. Look down at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I did not see anything in log pane. When I try to open SQL Worksheet.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes, I am getting `null at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.OpenWorksheetWizard.openNewTempWorksheet(OpenWorksheetWizard.java:509)` error in log pane.

Comment: very weird, a hail mary, try Window > Reset Windows to Factory Settings - this will reset your SQLDev desktop layout.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith After Reset Windows to Factory Settings no progress. I am facing this issue again.

Comment: All I can guess is a 'bad' install. try unzipping to a new directory, and on startup, say 'no' to importing previous preferences/settings

Comment: @thatjeffsmith unzipping to a new directory?

Comment: yeah, your 4.1.5 download from OTN - it's a zip file. Extract the contents to an empty directory - dont' overwrite an existing copy of SQLDev

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Delete "SQL Developer" and "sqldeveloper" folders from C:\Users\user001\AppData\Roaming location. Extract "sqldeveloper-4.1.5.21.78-x64.zip" file in a new fresh location and run Oracle SQL Developer with 'no' to importing previous preferences/setting. After connecting to database I am able to connect with database but SQL Worksheet not open and I am getting the same error `null at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.OpenWorksheetWizard.openNewTempWorksheet(OpenWorksheetWizard.java:509)` on log pane.

Comment: no idea, you must have gremlins in your machine. you can run sqldev in debug mode to get more verbose logging to the panel http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/10/using-debug-mode-in-oracle-sql-developer-to-log-sql/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I just update my question with one image of full error description. Can you please look into this.

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you launching SQL Developer directly by double-clicking sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper.exe, or are you using a shortcut or batch file wrapper? Do you have any extensions, or unusual JDK installation or settings? Wondering if it's worth trying a newer clean JDK version and/or SD 4.2.0 but can't see why either would make a difference if a fresh 4.2.5 didn't.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes. I am launching SQL Developer directly by double-clicking sqldeveloper.exe. Should I have to reinstall my JDK?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to, but if a fresh copy of SQL Developer doesn't fix it then JDK seems like the next thing to try. Or running in debug mode as Jeff suggested. He's in a much better position to help you figure this out than anyone else, but only if you let him.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced this and finally found the issue. This has happend because of antivirus(kaspeskey). 
So, disabled the antivirus, it works fine.

Comment: So you had sql developer open and running with GUI showing ok, but could not open a worksheet until you disabled anitvirus?

Comment: Weird, very weird. What version of SQLDev and Java?

Comment: Yes it's Weird. I'm using Java 1.6 & oracle - 4.1.3.

Comment: Both of those are pretty old, I'd update to SQLDev 18.1 and Java 8